# ERR_SSL_VERSION_OR_CIPHER_MISMATCH

Tags: linux, tomcat, ssl-certificate, azure

I have set up my SSL configuration in an Azure Ubuntu VM using Tomcat8. The service seems to be running on port 8443. I have created an endpoint on Azure from public port 443 to 8443.

However, when I run `https://example.com` I get error `ERR_SSL_VERSION_OR_CIPHER_MISMATCH`.

This is the `server.xml`:

```
<Connector port="8443" protocol="org.apache.coyote.http11.Http11NioProtocol"
               maxThreads="150" SSLEnabled="true" scheme="https" secure="true"
               clientAuth="false" sslProtocol="TLS"
               keystoreFile="/home/me/example.com.ssl/example.com.jks"
               keystorePass="examplePasswd" keystoreType="JKS"/>
```

The alias of the certificate is "tomcat". However, if I add  keyAlias="tomcat" in the Connector, I get an error "unknown alias".

I have uploaded all the root, intermediate and domain certificates to Azure cloud services.

Any ideas why it is failing?

Comment: Is the alias for your certificate `Tomcat`?

Comment: the alias is "tomcat" in lower case. However, if I add  keyAlias="tomcat" in the Connector, I get an error "unknown alias". Could it be a problem?

Comment: Unfortunately the error `ERR_SSL_VERSION_OR_CIPHER_MISMATCH` can mean anything. How did you create the SSL certifiacte? Did you import all the certificate into the keystore?

Comment: I followed the steps for PEM installation in http://helpdesk.ssls.com/hc/en-us/articles/203505171-How-to-install-a-SSL-certificate-on-a-Tomcat-server

Comment: Did you generate the certificate yourself with 'keytool'? If yes, did you add the '-keyalg RSA'?